# I'm trying trying to Insert Into but error psycopg2 "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm trying to Insert Into values in a Table using psycopg2 but i can't.

What i need:

```
Insert into a table from (select ...)
```

I need to insert any row from a specific select, like this:

```
insert into table (
createdat_date,
createdat_date_year_month,
createdat_date_month,
createdat_date_month_name,
type,
empresa,
sum_1,
sum_2,
sum_4,
sum_4,
sum_5,
count_1)
values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
```

```
select_query= '''
select
t._createdat_date,
t._createdat_date_year_month,
t._createdat_date_month,
t._createdat_date_month_name,
t."type",
empresas,
sum(pe) sum_1,
sum(p2) sum_1,
sum(char) sum_1,
sum(cash1) sum_1,
sum(cash2) sum_1,
count(finan) count_1
from table1 t
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
'''
```

```
cur.execute(insert_query_transactions,select_query_transactions)
```

Could someone help me? I spend a lot time to solve it.

I also tried to declare just

```
insert into table select that query

cur.execute(insert_query)
```

But the data has not been changed in the database.

Edit: please answer this topic with script I havent been understanding what you saying. But this topic is different from the other ones.

Comment: 1) Read this [SO code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) 2) More importantly read [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Hint, you cannot use `select_query` to directly pass in the parameter values. You will need to run that query and collect the results into the form that the passing parameters link shows.

Answer (score 2):

You can do without any prepared statement

```
insert into table (
createdat_date,
createdat_date_year_month,
createdat_date_month,
createdat_date_month_name,
type,
empresa,
sum_1,
sum_2,
sum_4,
sum_4,
sum_5,
count_1)
select`enter code here`
 t._createdat_date,
 t._createdat_date_year_month,
 t._createdat_date_month,
 t._createdat_date_month_name,
 t."type",
 empresas,
 sum(pe) sum_1,
 sum(p2) sum_1,
 sum(char) sum_1,
 sum(cash1) sum_1,
 sum(cash2) sum_1,
 count(finan) count_1
 from table1 t
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Hey mate, I has already tried justcur.execute(query_insert) but the data has not been changed in the database

Comment: You need to commit or have Auto commit enabled

Comment: Can you explain better? I didn't understand.

Comment: Sure, `conn.commit()` must be run to make changes persistent conn is the SQL connection

Comment: It has worked, thank you